# Applescript has a limit of the number of lines.

Tags: applescript, limit, lines

I am making an app with a TON of features. My problem is that applescript seems to have a cut-off point. After a certain number of lines, the script stopps working. It basically only works until the end. Once it gets to that point it stops. I have moved the code around to make sure that it is not an error within the code. Help?

Comment: It only works until the end? Hm... is that a typo or I just don't get it?

Comment: @FatalError That wasn't a typo, but it was kinda vague. Everything works except after a certain length of the script.

Comment: AppleScript does have various practical limits which cause scripts to begin to fail once they grow too long.  However, when this happens you will start to see stack overflow and other types of errors appearing rather than a script simply stopping at a certain point.

Do you happen to have block-style comments (* … *) in your script?  The rules for these types of comments are complex and its possible to accidentally escape large blocks of code.  For instance, this can happen if you have unclosed string literals within your block comments.

Comment: @MarkAlldritt I don't think my script is too complex. It is majorly text inputs and if-then statements.

Comment: I suspect that some part of your scripts logic leads to it completing earlier than you expect. Try and go through each step using for example the say command. Put say 1 at the start and then say 2 at the start of the next step in the code and say 3 after it. Keep doing this through out the script. This may help you see which steps are being hit and completed and if they are in the order you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I believe a long script is not a good way to put your code.
It's really hard to read, to debug or to maintain as one slight change in a part can have unexpected consequences at the other part of you file.

If your script is very long, I suggest you break your code in multiple parts.

First, you may use functions if some part of the code is reused several times.
Another benefit of the functions is that you can validate them separately from the rest of the execution code.
Besides, it makes your code easier to read.

```
on doWhatYouHaveTo(anArgument)
 say "hello!"
end doWhatYouHaveTo
```

If the functions are used by different scripts, you may want to have your functions in a seperate library that you will call at need.

```
set cc to load script alias ((path to library folder as string) & "Scripts:Common:CommonLibrary.app")
cc's doWhatYouHaveTo(oneArgument)
```

At last, a thing that I sometimes do is calling a different script with some arguments, if a long code fits for slightly different purposes:

```
run script file {mainFileName} with parameters {oneWay}
```

This last trick has a great yet curious benefit : it can accelerate the execution time for a reason I never explained (and when I say accelerate, I say reduce execution time by 17 or so for the very same code).